# How can I move all the controls in a panel on form resize?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, controls, resize

I'm playing around with a project, C# .NET 4, and I'm kind of stuck. I have with a panel that will be dynamically filled with checkboxes based on the number of items in a folder, which works fine.

But when I resize the form I want the checkboxes to move in the panel, like a little grid of checkboxes that takes up what space it can.

Thus far I have been unsuccessful in finding an efficient way to do this. I still haven't gotten it to work flat out yet, but I don't know that it matters. The methods I'm trying are resource killers.

ie.

```
int boxCount = panel1.Size.Width/123;
int x = 3, y = 3, i = 0;

foreach (Control chkbox in panel1.Controls)
{

      if (i < boxCount)
      {
            chkbox.Location = new Point(x, y);
            x += 123;
      }
      else
      {
            i = 0;
            x = 3;
            y += 123;
            chkbox.Location = new Point(x, y);
      }

      i++;
}
```

I'm looking for something that doesn't put my CPU in a choke hold and turn my form into a 3 page flip book when I resize it. For reference, I had something like the Windows desktop wallpaper selector in 7 in mind, minus the resizing of the actual controls.

I've not worked with WPF, but I am likely to start having been shown the light, so I was looking a garden variety Windows Forms solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx).

Comment: That works beautifully. I remember thinking there should be a control for this, but never looked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) or a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) meet your needs?